# jQuery replaceWith not working while replacing with three elements

Tags: jquery, html, replacewith

I'm trying to replace a single element with three other elements, using jQuery's replaceWith, but it doesn't seem to be working.

HTML:

```
<span>first</span>
<span>second</span>
<span>third</span>
```

JS:

```
var spans = $("span");
spans.eq(1).replaceWith("<span></span><span></span><span></span>");
```

This should if I'm write, result in:

```
<span>first</span>
<span></span><span></span><span></span>
<span>third</span>
```

But nothing changes...any thoughts?

**EDIT:** This was meant as an example, I didn't take into account a difference between actual dom and generated dom (is there a difference?  It appears so...)

```
var spans = $("<span>first</span><span>second</span><span>third</span>");
spans.eq(1).replaceWith($("<span></span><span></span><span></span>"));
```

So there's a more accurate portrayal of my code.

Comment: works for me http://jsfiddle.net/yads/z9VDw/

Comment: Yeah, it seems that my code example was flawed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit.** Check http://jsfiddle.net/z9VDw/3/ . Seems you have to append disconnected DOM nodes before doing such manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

Now that I see what you're trying to do it won't work. Dom manipulation with fragments doesn't work in jQuery. (Other than setting attributes/css.) `replaceWith` inserts the value before the next elements. In this case `<span>third</span>` and then returns `this` again, which is whatever `this` was before you called `replaceWith`. Which was `<span>second</span>`

Comment: Okay, so how do I accomplish this?